# Camera timer intent

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, camera, basic4android

I need to use the camera for my application with a countdown timer. That is, when called, the camera should open with an automatic 3-second timer via intent.
So far, I am able to open the system camera, take a picture and save it. But now how to set an automatic timer?

My code:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "an automatic 3-second timer" means. Do you mean after three seconds, you want to call `startActivityForResult()`? Do you mean that you want to call `startActivityForResult()`, and then the camera should take a picture automatically in three seconds? Do you mean something else?

Comment: No, I mean I want to set a "countdown timer", after the camera has launched. Something like this: [ScreenShot](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android-galaxy-mega-timed-photos-4.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you want would appear to be what I described in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267188/camera-timer-intent?noredirect=1#comment69735216_41267188) as "you want to call `startActivityForResult()`, and then the camera should take a picture automatically in three seconds". That is what the timer option in [the screenshot](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android-galaxy-mega-timed-photos-4.png) in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267188/camera-timer-intent/41283389#comment69768127_41267188) would do, AFAICT.

If so, that is not possible in general. There are thousands of camera apps, both pre-installed on devices and available through distribution channels like the Play Store. Few have timers. None have to offer an API to allow you to configure a timer.

You can:

- Try find a camera app that does have an API to allow you to configure a timer, then require the user to install that camera app
- Integrate with the camera APIs directly yourself
- Wait for me to [add this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/297) to [my CWAC-Cam2 library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2)